# JS Busy loading indicator ignore middle click

Tags: javascript, button, mouse

My busy loading indicator basically works by detecting clicks. However, I just noted that when I middle click an item, it opens a link in a new tab and then the loading indicator shows up forever. How can I tell JS to ignore the middle mouse button?

```
 window.onload = setupFunc;

     function setupFunc() {
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = clickFunc;
       hideBusysign();
         Wicket.Ajax.registerPreCallHandler(showBusysign);
         Wicket.Ajax.registerPostCallHandler(hideBusysign);
         Wicket.Ajax.registerFailureHandler(hideBusysign);
     }

     function hideBusysign() {
       document.getElementById('busy').style.display ='none';
     }

     function showBusysign() {
       document.getElementById('busy').style.display ='inline';
     }

     function clickFunc(eventData) {
       var clickedElement = (window.event) ? event.srcElement : eventData.target;
       if (clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A' || clickedElement.parentNode.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'A'
         || (clickedElement.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT' && (clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'SUBMIT'))) {
         showBusysign();
       }
     }
```

Comment: Did you want to steal the middle click to not open in a new tab, or did you want your progress-loading indicator to not be triggered when the middle click is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to, but it won't work very well with all browsers.

[This page](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html) describes what browsers support disabling the middle mouse button via JS. Firefox is not one of them...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to scope the click events to only work on *AJAX* links/buttons.

For instance (rewriting with jQuery only b/c I'm hopeless without it):

```
// On load
$(function() {
  Wicket.Ajax.registerPreCallHandler(showBusysign);
  Wicket.Ajax.registerPostCallHandler(hideBusysign);
  Wicket.Ajax.registerFailureHandler(hideBusysign);
});    

// Assuming you add an "ajax" class to all appropriate markup (in Wicket)

// .live would be appropriate, too
$('body').delegate('a.ajax, input:button.ajax, input:submit.ajax', 'click', function(){
  showBusysign();
});
```